# Calling a variable as a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def f(x):
    def g():
        x='abc'
        print('x=',x)
    def h():
        z=x
        print('z=',z)
    x=x+1
    print('x=',x)
    h()
    g()
    print('x=',x)
    return g
x=3
z=f(x)
print('x=',x)
print('z=',z)
z()
```

**Output**

```
x= 4
z= 4
x= abc
x= 4
x= 3
z= <function f.<locals>.g at 0x000000F6919EF9D8>
x= abc
```

I don't understand how we call `z()` as a function when it is a variable. Also, I don't understand how we got the last 2 lines of output.

Comment: `f(x)` returns `g` which is a function, hence calling `z()` will call `g()`.

Comment: @Austin but z=f(x), so why does calling z() not execute the print statements in f()?

Comment: why should it execute prints inside `f()`?

Comment: @Austin the statement z=f(x) executes all the print statements within f, then why is z() different?

Comment: please read the answer posted below. `z` is holding only the returned value from function `f(x)`. That returned value happened to be a function. So calling `z()` calls that function and that function includes only one print statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in python all objects are first class objects. you can assign names (variables) to any object; that includes functions.

the relevant parts of your first question are:

```
def f(x):
    def g():
        x='abc'
    return g
```

i.e. `f` returns a function. you can assign and call it with:

```
z = f(3)
print(z)  # <function f.<locals>.g at 0x000000F6919EF9D8>
z()
```

for your second question: `print(z)` (see in the code above) will generate a line of output and calling `z()` (i.e. `g()`) will print `x= abc`.